# check existence of two values in two columns in either order?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, visual-studio

I have a table in the database; it has three columns.
The first (Friends_Id) is (int) primary key and the others are (User_1 & User_2) nvarchar(50).

Every (User_1 & User_2) occurs once.
The order of the values in (User_1 & User_2) is not important. Which means that the values "A" and "B" can be put in this table in either of the following ways:

```
------------------------------
| Friends_Id | User_1| User_2 |
------------------------------
|    37      |   A   |   B    |
------------------------------
```

Or:

```
------------------------------
| Friends_Id | User_1| User_2 |
------------------------------
|    37      |   B   |   A    |
------------------------------
```

Of course "A" can appear many times but with values other than "B".
The same is true for "B"; it can appear with values other than "A".

The **Question** is: How to check the existence of ("A","B") or ("B","A") using LINQ to entities in C#.
The query must answer the question: Is there an occurrence of "A" and "B" in either order ("A","B") or ("B","A") in the columns (User_1, User_2).

Comment: `return Convert.ToBoolean(repository.Where( x => (x.User_1 == "A" && x.User_2 == "B") || (x.User_1 == "B" && x.User_2 == "A")).Count());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this may work :

```
int count = (from row in table
where (row.user_1 == "A" && row.user_2 == "B") || (row.user_1 == "B" && row.user_2 == "A"))
.Count();

if(count > 0)
{
    // your code
}
```

or a better approach is using `Any()`:

```
if(context.table.Any(r => (r.User_1 == "A" && r.User_2 == "B") || (r.User_1 == "B" && r.User_2 == "A")))
{
    // your code
}
```